# Laravel 5.6 distribute routes by user params

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5, routes

In the routes `app/routes/web.php` I have a group with a bunch of routes for resources:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
   Route::get('/points', 'PagesController@points');
   Route::get('/users', 'PagesController@users');
   Route::get('/users/groups', 'PagesController@user_groups');
   Route::resource('point', 'PointController');
   Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
   Route::resource('users/group', 'UserGroupController');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/logout', 'Auth\LoginController@logout')->name('logout');
```

And now I want to distribute routes in this group by user parameter:

```
use App\UserGroup;

$access = UserGroup::find( auth()->user()->group_id )->access;

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function()
{
   if ($access == 1) {
      Route::get('/points', 'PagesController@points');
      Route::get('/users', 'PagesController@users');
      Route::get('/users/groups', 'PagesController@user_groups');
      Route::resource('point', 'PointController');
      Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
      Route::resource('users/group', 'UserGroupController');
   }
});
```

But I can't get user params right in the `Route::group` because an error occurs: `Trying to get property 'group_id' of non-object`

How to get `auth()->user()->group_id` in `app/routes/web.php` before middleware?

Answer (score 1):

Use $access param in callback

```
$access = UserGroup::find( auth()->user()->group_id )->access

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() use ($access)
{
   if ($access == 1) {
      Route::get('/points', 'PagesController@points');
      Route::get('/users', 'PagesController@users');
      Route::get('/users/groups', 'PagesController@user_groups');
      Route::resource('point', 'PointController');
      Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
      Route::resource('users/group', 'UserGroupController');
   }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Anyways I can access `auth()->user()` only inside `Route::get` function but not before `Route::group` or right inside it.

Answer (score 1):

U can [create](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#defining-middleware) middleware 'GroupAccess'. Then [assign it to alias](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/middleware#registering-middleware), i.e.

```
'groupAccess' => \App\Http\Middleware\GroupAccess::class
```

Finally in it's handle method check your condition

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if (UserGroup::find( auth()->user()->group_id )->access === 1)
        return $next($request);
    else
        return back();
}
```

Then just specify this middleware in route group

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','groupAccess']], function()
{
      Route::get('/points', 'PagesController@points');
      Route::get('/users', 'PagesController@users');
      Route::get('/users/groups', 'PagesController@user_groups');
      Route::resource('point', 'PointController');
      Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
      Route::resource('users/group', 'UserGroupController');
});
```

Comment: Thanks! But now an error occurs: `Class groupAccess does not exist`

Comment: You need to register your middleware first. I updated my answer, check it pls

Comment: try to replace `return back();` to `return redirect('/');`

Comment: Thanks a lot, I've added `GroupAccess` class to all middleware arrays in the Kernel but now new error occured in the recently created middleware `GroupAccess.php`: `Trying to get property 'group_id' of non-object`

Comment: never place middleware to `protected $middleware` if you don't need to run it during every request to your application. It may trigger that error in your case.

Comment: I am very appreciating your help. I've removed `GroupAccess` class from `protected $middleware` in the `Kernel.php` and replaced `return back();` with `return redirect('/');` in `GroupAccess.php` but still have an issue with page loading inspite that fact that it actually redirects to `'/'` path (page is not available now).